# No signature of method in flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/1726mohitraj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/audioplayers_android-3.0.1/android/build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':audioplayers_android'.

> No signature of method: build_91u1y9cmlwptitkd488tz946b.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_91u1y9cmlwptitkd488tz946b$_run_closure2) values: [build_91u1y9cmlwptitkd488tz946b$_run_closure2@745e6edd]

code in '/Users/1726mohitraj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/audioplayers_android-3.0.1/android/build.gradle' :

```
group 'xyz.luan.audioplayers'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    ext.coroutines_version = '1.6.4'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.7.1.1"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'de.mannodermaus.android-junit5'

android {
    compileSdk 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    
    lint {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.0'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.23.1'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I tried to comment out each line in android{...} and run the project but then also it doesn't work. I also tried to Invalidate caches and restart the project but still didn't get any output.

Comment: Did you also change `distributionUrl` in gradle-wrapper.properties ?
https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/9f39e95ff7913d8fc30fff27fef7aefc32de26fb/packages/audioplayers/example/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L6

Answer (score 2):

This issue appears because the project you are working on has an old version of Android Gradle Plugin (AGP). Lots of Flutter plugins started to update their Android part to support recent releases of AGP. Namely, since Android Gradle Plugin 8 it is required to declare a `namespace` property in `build.gradle` file of the project: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/5-ways-to-prepare-your-app-build-for-android-studio-flamingo-release-da34616bb946 (couldn't link exact step mentioning this).
This `namespace` property appeared only in Android Gradle Plugin 4.2. Here is an explanation in a Github issue about the samem problem you have: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/125621#issuecomment-1525995461

Based on that the solution to your issue is to go in `android` -> `build.gradle` and update Android Gradle Plugin version. I would recommend to go with something like `7.4.2` as it is the last version before 8.x.x and versions 8.x.x are not fully supported by packages like `integration_test` yet (as of May 2023).

Here is how the line with AGP version looks like: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/battery_plus/battery_plus/android/build.gradle#L11
Note, if you had AGP pre 4.2 it is highly likely that to update to 7.x you would also need to update your Gradle wrapper version. Here is where you can find the line to modify Gradle wrapper version: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/battery_plus/battery_plus/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L3

Some Flutter plugins decided to go a way of not adding a workaround to support pre 4.2 versions of AGP and it includes Plus Plugins, where I was the person who decided that with a new major release we could encourage people to update their Android native part of the project to benefit from all the improvements Google and Gradle teams are working on.

Answer (score 1):

Remove following code from android Tag in Build.gradle file which is located at **/Users/1726mohitraj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/audioplayers_android-3.0.1/android/build.gradle**

```
lint {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
```

After that save gradle file and re run your project. If doesn't work then try to comment in android Tag line by line and save and re run project until it works. This way you will be able resolve your issue.

Comment: That fixed the error for `audioplayers_android` but I get the same error for `connectivity_plus` where this does not fix the error. Any idea?

Comment: @Jonas you need to fix connectivity_plus build.gradle file too. This file will be located in /Users/1726mohitraj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/connectivity_plus. You need to repeat the process described above for that gradle file.

Comment: @ Programmer007 I tried that but it does not fix it. This gradle file has only has the `lintOptions` property and not the `lint` property, I'm not sure what the difference is bit I tried to remove the `lintOptions` property any way and I still get the same error

Comment: @Jonas if feasible share code i can check what's wrong.

Comment: thanks for the help. Please check out my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304432/flutter-package-build-error-no-signature-of-method. Not sure what further code I should share, please let me know.

Comment: This answer is not a solution, because it is just modifying the code of some plugin in your local cache which will be overwritten next time you update some dependencies and run `pub get` command.

@Jonas You need to update Android Gradle Plugin version in `build.gradle` file in `android` folder of your project. Looks like you have AGP older than 4.2. I have mentioned it explicitly in the changelogs for `connectivity_plus` that we don't support such old versions anymore: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus/changelog#400