# Flutter package build error No signature of method

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to run my flutter application on an emulator using the package `connectivity_plus: ^4.0.1` but I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/jonas/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/connectivity_plus-4.0.1/android/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':connectivity_plus'.
> No signature of method: build_e6loa2x19fg7jkftcahbdmkjg.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_e6loa2x19fg7jkftcahbdmkjg$_run_closure2) values: [build_e6loa2x19fg7jkftcahbdmkjg$_run_closure2@7fabfc33]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,643ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with physical device?

Comment: @ZeeshanAyaz no, don't have one around

Answer (score 0):

I changed the build.gradle file in the pub-cache of connectivity_plus like the following and it worked for me:

```
group 'io.flutter.plugins.connectivity'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}
```